# Unit testing dialog componentInstance event emitter in entry component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I have an entry Dialog component(EntryDialog) and an actual Dialog component(MyDialog). I have a subscriber in entry component which is subscribing to an event emitter in my main dialog component. Struggling with testing this below part, would appreciate your help.

#### Part to test

> ```
> this.dialogRef.componentInstance.myEventEmitter.subscribe((type: string) => {
>   if (type) {
>     this.assignSample(type);
>   }
> });
> ```

#### Entry Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-entry-dialog',
})
@Component({template: ''})
export class EntryDialog {
  dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialog>;
  constructor(
      private readonly dialog: MatDialog,
  ) {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialog, {
      data: someData,
      disableClose: true,
    });
    this.dialogRef.componentInstance.myEventEmitter.subscribe((type: string) => {
      if (type) {
        this.assignSample(type);
      }
    });
  }

  private assignSample(type: string) {
    // some code here
  }
```

#### Main Dialog Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-dialog',
  templateUrl: './my_dialog.ng.html',
})
export class MyDialog {
  @Output() myEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<string>(true);

  constructor(
      @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) readonly sample: string,
      public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialog>,
  ) {
    merge(
        this.dialogRef.backdropClick(),
        this.dialogRef.keydownEvents().pipe(filter(
            (keyboardEvent: KeyboardEvent) => keyboardEvent.key === 'Escape')))
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.dialogRef.close();
        });
  }

  emitEvent() {
    this.myEventEmitter.emit("data");
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a mock for it, and you don't need even TestBed here.

```js
it('', () => {
  // creating mocked dependencies
  const mockDialogRef: any = {
    componentInstance: {
      myEventEmitter: new Subject(),
    },
  };
  const mockMatDialog: any = {
    open: jasmine.createSpy(),
  };

  mockMatDialog.open.and.returnValue(mockDialogRef);

  // action
  const instance = new EntryDialog(mockMatDialog);

  // checking open call
  expect(mockMatDialog.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(MyDialog, {
    data: someData,
    disableClose: true,
  });

  mockDialogRef.componentInstance.myEventEmitter.next('typeToTest');
  // assertions 
});
```